# Searching for a string that contains the file name

Tags: text-processing, grep, search, file-search

I have a large set of files in a directory. The files contains arbitrary text.

I want to search for the file name inside that particular file text. To clarify, I have `file1.py.txt` (yeas, two dots `.py.txt`) and `file2.py.txt` both contains texts. I want to search for the existence of the string `@code prefix.file1.py` inside `file1.py.txt` and for the string `@code prefix.file2.py` inside `file2.py.txt`

How can I customize `grep` such that it goes through every file in the directory, search for the string in each file using that particular file name?

**EDIT:**

The output I am looking for is written in a separate file, `result.txt` which contains:
filename (if a match is found), the line text (where the match is found)

Comment: What output are you wanting? A list of filenames that satisfy the condition, or the list of lines from those files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With GNU `awk`:

```
gawk '
  BEGINFILE{search = "@code prefix." substr(FILENAME, 3, length(FILENAME) - 6)}
  index($0, search)' ./*.py.txt
```

Would report the matching lines.

To print the file name and matching line, change `index($0, search)` to

```
  index($0, search) {print FILENAME": "$0}
```

Or to print the file name only:

```
  index($0, search) {print FILENAME; nextfile}
```

Replace `FILENAME` with `substr(FILENAME, 3)` to skip outputting the `./` prefix.

The list of files is lexically sorted. The ones whose name starts with `.` are ignored (some shells have a `dotglob` option to add them back; with `zsh`, you can also use the `(D)` glob qualifier).

Comment: your solution should be faster. This is printing the string `@code ...`, while mine prints the filename.

Comment: @Jay, it would be faster as longer as if the files are relatively small as only one command is run. For large files, running several `grep`s may end up being faster as `grep` implementations are generally  faster at matching than `gawk`. I've added alternatives to only  print the file names.

Answer (score 3):

It is needed to grep each file found.

`-l` instructs `grep` to print the filename only when the `regex` is found.

If the filenames does not contain any `/` char, give a try to this:

```
find a_directory -type f -name \*.py.txt -exec sh -c '
  for fname; do
    basename="${fname##*/}"
    grep -lF "@code prefix.${basename%.*}" "${fname}"
  done' sh {} +
```

see `man bash` for the items below:

- `"${fname##*/}"` is `file1.py.txt`, if `fname` == `a_directory/file1.py.txt`
- `"${basename%.*}"` is `file1.py`, if `basename` == `file1.py.txt`

Comment: There is no need to use find at all if the files are in a given directory, just loop through the results of print *.py.txt

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: thx! I will switch soon to `-exec ... ` instead of `| xargs`. I did not thought about the `fgrep`

Comment: @RamanSailopal: in general ... yes. In this particular situation, a substring of the filename is searched inside the text file, so I do not think there is a solution with `grep ... *.py.txt`

Comment: @Jay, you could always do `for fname in *.py.txt`

Comment: Tested ok with filenames with exotic chars (`"`,` `, `\n`) ; I am surprised because the `for` loop did not break.